# Case Analysis - which of two potential alternatives is correct?

Tags: medieval-latin, grammar-identification

I have several sentences from c1700 of the form:

Ad hanc Curiam venit Johannes unus Tenentium Custumariorum hujus Manerii qui tenuit sibi pro termino vitæ suæ naturalis per Copiam Curiae Rotuli gerens datum decimo sexto die Mensis Octobris Anno Domini 1664 totum illum Cottagium.......

Which has been translated as:
To this Court came John one of the Customary tenants of this Manor who held to himself for the term of his natural life by the Copy of a Court Roll bearing the date sixth day of October Anno Domini 1664 the whole of that Customary cottage......

My query is on the case of gerens (bearing), which in the original script is contracted to geren, leaving the transcriber to decide the case. Currently I have used accusative (to match Copiam - which follows per), but should it be genitive (to match Curiae Rotuli)? A good reasoning would be appreciated.

Comment: I should have made it clear the original script just has "geren" as a contracted word, so the ending is left to the transcriber - hence the query.

Comment: You say _you_ used accusative—are you composing these sentences or finding them in a source from c 1700? That'll affect the answers we give.

Comment: Oh, well, that answers that. Mind if I edit it into the question?

Comment: Feel free to improve.

Comment: Nope, your clarification is good, the question makes perfect sense to me now. Unfortunately I can't offer a good answer because this depends on the exact semantics of _copia_, and the word meant something very different in 1700 than in the first century CE.

Comment: All I can add is (at this period) tenancy changes were recorded by a local Manorial Court and a (physical) copy of the Court record was given to the new tenant as proof of his right to tenure. In some Court entries I have "copia facta" (which I believe is copy made).